# Inconceivable objects. What can make them become conceivable?

Tags: ontology

Are there such objects or phenomena that we can't comprehend or imagine?

Can objects like round square or the largest number be reffered as inconceivable? Can we assume that objects that are inconceivable today will be conceivable or even real tomorrow? What can make them become conceivable?

Comment: Well a square is a definition, this is an uninteresting truth. The square "just is" the definition of a square. As far as numbers go, this area is outside of my knowledge, better let the number people answer that question. As far as the rest of your questions, you are a Hegelian, you may already know that. Things don't stay "frozen" unless they are uninteresting. You can download Marcuse's Reason & Revolution from Internet  Archive for free.

Comment: Glenn Alexander Magee's "The Hegel Dictionary" is still available for purchase I think, and I have seen it floating around as a PDF. Anyway you may already have such materials, and it could be you have no interest in Hegel at all, and if so I apologize.

Comment: The unit circle in the L^1 or taxicab metric is a square. I wish people wouldn't talk about square circles. They're perfectly sensible mathematical objects. There's a picture of a square circle here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are objects like an electric field or a phonograph that were inconceivable to primitive humans of Stone Age. And there are modern devices like micro chips or lasers or cell phones that were inconceivable to people 200 years ago because the effects they are based upon were far out of reach even for advanced physicists of that time. It is inconceivable that this series will stop. (And if it would then this very fact is inconceivable today.)